# Merge existing HDD and SSD into Fusion drive

Tags: ssd, fusion-drive, hdd

Some time ago I split the Fusion Drive into 2 parts, SSD and HDD accordingly. Now I decided to return to fusion drive, but I have some data that I would like to keep.

Is it possible to merge drives back into fusion drive without need to reformat drives?

UPD

```
sudo gpt -r show disk0
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  235298960      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  235708600    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236978136          7         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header

sudo gpt -r show disk1
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1951845952      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1952255592     1269543         
  1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
  1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Not a task I'd even consider attempting without a solid backup in place first.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo gpt -r show disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show disk1` entered in Terminal to your question. **Don't** post it as comment!

Comment: @klanomath updated my question